# Exporting a table from Earth Engine to Cloud Storage using the npm package

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, node-js, google-cloud

I try to export a table from Google Earth Engine to Cloud storage with a script that runs using NodeJS instead of the code editor. However, when running the script, no file is added to the Cloud Storage bucket and no error message appears. Also I do not see the task listed in the task manager.

I use the following code, inspired by the example for the Python package for Earth Engine (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install?hl=nl#exporting-data)

```
const ee = require('@google/earthengine');

// Create locations
const points = [ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(4.8, 48.6)), ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(4.9, 48.7))];
const pointsFc = ee.FeatureCollection(points);

// Create a Sentinel2 collection
const collectionS2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31')
    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(pointsFc));

// Collect median values per band for this month
const FcS2 = collectionS2.reduceRegions({
    collection: pointsFc,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    scale: 10
});

// Export as CSV to Cloud Storage
const task = ee.batch.Export.table.toCloudStorage({
    collection: FcS2,
    description: 'MedianValuesS2_201801',
    bucket: 'test',
    fileNamePrefix: 's2_median_2018_01',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
task.start();
```

How should this work for JavaScript?